# How to generate Beta diversity boxplot from phyloseq object?

Tags: statistics

I am working with profiled metagenomic taxonomy abundance data. I want to generate beta diversity (bray-curtis) boxplot from a phyloseq object where two groups (control and test) will be shown. Something like this figure:

[image]

How can I make it? Can anyone share any code or tutorial?

Thanks,
dpc

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the phyloseq object to a dataframe and just plot it using base R or ggplot2. I'm not exactly sure what the bray curtis df will be called but you can access it using the @ notation then convert with data.frame e.g.

```
bray_for_plot <- data.frame(phylo_obj@bray)
```